# Are There Abbreviations/Acronyms/Codes for Cryptocurrency Exchanges?

Tags: exchanges, terminology

I wonder if there are any abbreviations/acronyms/codes for exchanges like Cryptsy, Kraken, and Ccex. Similar to abbreviations as seen for coins in `Bitcoin = BTC` and `Litecoin = LTC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are not such codes for Exchanges, like there aren't any codes for different websites. The codes for the different currencies are just for shortening I believe. It's easier anyhow for trading pairs (NMC/BTC instead of Namecoin/Bitcoin)

Comment: Thanks, but this code i mentioned here is not source code, rather name code for exchanges.

Comment: Im not sure what you want then. Do you want a trading bot or something like that?

Comment: For instance Bitcoin is called as btc, Litecoin as ltc, they are cryptocoins. Crypty, Kraken are exchanges, so do they have any code to refer them ?

Comment: Ahh, on that bike. I will update my answer